# Automatically convert " to `` or ''

Tags: punctuation

Is there any LaTeX option to treat " characters (ASCII 0x22) as either an opening quote or a closing quote, depending on whether it's at beginning or end of a word?

e.g. I supply the text like:

"hello", world.

and LaTeX would treat that as equivalent to:

``hello'', world.

Comment: If you use package `csquotes` you can write `\enquote{hello}, world.` You can define how the quotes should look.

Comment: It's reassuring that such a simple thing as this is a duplicate question already  ;)  Thanks for the links.